# How to splite with number with , in filed with missing number in given number?

Tags: java, string, split, stringbuilder

I am trying to getting this output. But failed to missing numbers in separate by this ',' one ?

```
Input: 1, 2, 3, 4.. 9, 10,13.. 17, 18, 19.. 25 
Output: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

Comment: **10,13** in input is there a space missing or is it actually like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working implementation which does what you need, further explanation below the code:

```
public static String getCSV(int start, int end) {
    List<String> list = IntStream.range(start, end).boxed()
       .map(i -> i.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    String csv = String.join(" ", list);

    return csv;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    String input = "1, 2, 3, 4.. 9, 10,13.. 17, 18, 19.. 25";
    input = input.replaceAll(",\\s*", " ");
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\.\\.\\s*(\\d+)");
    Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find( )) {
        int start = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        int end = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
        m.appendReplacement(stringBuffer, getCSV(start, end+1));
    }
    System.out.println(stringBuffer);
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

This approach uses a regex matcher to identify every pair of numbers which is in ellipsis (e.g. `4.. 9`), and then replaces it with a space separated continuous range from the starting to ending point.  Java 8 streams come in handy here, and the `getCSV()` method generates a string containing the sequence of numbers from the starting and ending input values.  Then, we need only iterate over the entire input, and replace each ellipsis using the helper method.

### Demo

Comment: You're doing his homework. What did the OP try he didn't mention.

Comment: @lalreddyp I'm happy to help you out, but next time you ask a question here please include your code and try to highlight where you got stuck.